# Understanding struct

Tags: c, struct

So I understand the basics of struct or so I thought. Our teacher posted some code today and didnt quite explain it. Here is the code.

```
//declaring struct
struct params{
     int var;
     int var2;
     int var3;
};

//.c for function(part that matters)  
void *estimatepartial(void *info) {

     struct params *params = (struct params*) info;
```

I get what the rest of the code is doing. I havent seen

```
struct params *params = (struct params*) info;
```

before from what i recall. If someone could explain me what this does or at least what it is called so I can look it up I'd appreciate it.

What I've tried:

- Looking up websites on struct initialization
- declaring structs online
- looking at random struct examples online

Comment: This is called [cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast). This line declares a pointer to struct and initializes it from `info` pointer by telling compiler to assume that `info` actually points to `struct params`.

Comment: So i get casts and what they do. This is for parallel programing. So you might not know how this works exactly but Im not quite sure what this does. I can speculate from what we talked about that it could do something about saving a value since its returning NULL but i still dont fully understand what benefit or use this has.

Comment: Technically, the cast is unnecessary because a `void *` is implicitly converted when assigned to a pointer.

Comment: This can be used to pass opaque parameters. That is some library code deals with a pointer to void knowing nothing about user types, while user code can cast to / from pointer to void to pointer to user type and propagate some user-defined data through a library. Typical example is `pthread_create` which accepts a pointer to void and passes it to thread entry point.

Comment: You should really provide more context. The benefit this has can only be understood in the context in which it's used. See [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @VTT I spoke to another teacher and he explained it and yours just helps bring it more into the area of threading appreciate it. And Sorry user3386109. I wasnt quite sure how to correctly ask the question.

Comment: @VTT: There are safer ways to use opaque structures. Using `void *` should be restricted to the smallest possible code, best not at all, expecially for beginners. It just works against the compiler trying to help write correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are typecasting `void pointer` to of pointer of type `struct params`.
You are using void pointer because `void` pointer can hold address of any type.
But you cannot dereference void pointer hence you need to type cast to actual type.

**Example:**

You are developing the `library` to provide functionality to third party application and you don't want share the definition of `struct param` to application.
The same can be achieved using `void pointer` as below.

```
void* createParams()
  {
     struct params *passStruct = malloc(sizeof(*passStruct));
     return (void  *)passStruct;
  }
```

and application calls this function to create the `Params` struct.

```
   void *paramhandle = createParams();
```

then uses `paramhandle` to call `estimatepartial`

```
estimatepartial(paramhandle);
```

Using `void *` you have abstracted the definition of `struct params`.

Comment: A note: an opaque struct (meaning pointer to a named struct with unknown contents and size) would be better way than using a void pointer, for this purpose.

Comment: @hyde Yes, except that OP hinted in the comments that the function in the question is being passed to `pthread_create`. So the function signature cannot be changed, and hence an opaque struct is not an option.

Comment: The answer was very useful. And i understand not wanting to add opaque pointer in. But it gives me something else to look over when I find the time. Appreciate it guys

Comment: @RutgerLuther: That's not an apaque pointer. This is a different concept. `void *` is basically an untyped pointer, but its usage adds a lot of complication not mentioned here. If your teacher can't explain that reasonable (and may can't), you should get a good textbook and read the standard. Asking particular questions won't help to get the whole picture.